# How can I deploy MERN app in railway.app?

Tags: reactjs, express

I have deployed MERN app separately in server and client on railway.app How to connect both of them?

Answer (score 0):

No worries got it.

Just fetch from deployed backend URL.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).